# index.php/hello instead of index.php?title=hello

Tags: php, url

I tried this but the result is as if I have entered a null for the get, the get title isn't returned(I know that this can work on my server because I have MediaWiki and it works as index.php/main_page) I want to use this method because I do not have access to .htaccess at the moment.

Thanks,

MuqMan

Comment: I know its possible because I use mediawiki and it works without .htaccess but I dont know what to do for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values in the URL that don't come after a `?` will not be put into the `$_GET` superglobal.  You will need to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead.

You will need to parse out the value you're looking for manually.

Comment: $x = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); $title = (count($x) > 2) ? end($x) : 'content'; $urlid = (strlen($title) > 0) ? $title : 'content'; I think this works best

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is an idea to put your "hello" value in POST instead of GET to reach it.
While you let the URL show the "hello" for cosmetic (SEO) reasons.

Comment: $_POST is a superglobal array in which you can add key and value pairs like this:
    $_POST["title"] = "hello";

and retract from the array like this:
    $titlevar = $_POST["title"];

Comment: I didn't end up using this code, I used: $x = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); $title = (count($x) > 2) ? end($x) : 'content'; $urlid = (strlen($title) > 0) ? $title : 'content'; so I cannot really say but this code that I am using works.

Comment: I guess this is a bit late but I think you deserve the upvote